# Getting uncalibrated probability outputs with Vowpal Wabbit, ad-conversion prediction

Tags: probability, logistic-regression, vowpalwabbit

I'm trying to use Vowpal Wabbit to predict conversion rate for ads display and I'm getting non-intuitive probability outputs, which are centered at around 36% when the global frequency of the positive class is less than 1%.

The positive/negative imbalance I have in my dataset is 1/100 (I already undersampled the negative class), so I use a weight of 100 in the positive examples.

Negative examples have label -1, and positive ones 1. I used `shuf` to shuffle positive and negative examples for online learning to work properly.

Sample lines in the vw file:

```
1 100 'c4ac3440|i search_delay_log:3.58351893846 click_count_log:3.58351893846 banner_impression_count_log:3.98898404656 |c es i_type_2 xvertical_1_61 vertical_1 creat_size_728x90 retargeting
-1 1 'a4d25cf1|i search_delay_log:11.2825684591 click_count_log:11.2825684591 banner_impression_count_log:4.48863636973 |c br i_type_1 xvertical_1_960 vertical_1 creat_size_300x600 retargeting
```

Now I use the following to create a model from a training set:

```
vw -d impressions_rand.aa --loss_function logistic -c -k --passes 12 -f model.vw
```

Output:

```
final_regressor = model.vw
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
decay_learning_rate = 1
creating cache_file = impressions_rand.aa.cache
Reading datafile = impressions_rand.aa
num sources = 1
average  since         example        example  current  current  current
loss     last          counter         weight    label  predict features
0.693147 0.693147            1            1.0  -1.0000   0.0000       11
0.510760 0.328374            2            2.0  -1.0000  -0.9449       11
0.387521 0.264282            4            4.0  -1.0000  -1.1825       11
1.765374 1.818883            8          107.0   1.0000  -1.7020       11
2.152669 2.444504           51          249.0   1.0000  -3.2953       11
1.289870 0.427071          201          498.0  -1.0000  -3.5498       11
0.878843 0.528943          588         1083.0   1.0000  -1.3394        9
0.852358 0.825872         1176         2166.0  -1.0000  -6.7918       11
0.871977 0.891597         2451         4332.0  -1.0000  -2.7031       11
0.689428 0.506878         4110         8664.0  -1.0000  -2.7525       11
0.638008 0.586589         8517        17328.0  -1.0000  -5.8017       11
0.580220 0.522713        17515        34741.0   1.0000   2.1519       11
0.526281 0.472343        35525        69482.0  -1.0000  -6.2931        9
0.497601 0.468921        71050       138964.0  -1.0000  -7.6245        9
0.479305 0.461008       143585       277928.0  -1.0000  -0.8296       11
0.443734 0.443734       288655       555856.0  -1.0000  -2.5795       11 h
0.438806 0.433925       578181      1111791.0   1.0000   0.8503       11 h

finished run
number of examples per pass = 216000
passes used = 5
weighted example sum = 2072475.000000
weighted label sum = -67475.000000
average loss = 0.432676 h
best constant = -0.065138
best constant's loss = 0.692617
total feature number = 11548690
```

Now to predict on a test set. The `--link logistic` should transform the vw outputs to probabilities in the range `[0, 1]`.

```
vw -d impressions_rand.ab --link logistic -i model.vw -p preds_ab.txt
```

Output:

```
predictions = preds_ab.txt
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
using no cache
Reading datafile = impressions_rand.ab
num sources = 1
average  since         example        example  current  current  current
loss     last          counter         weight    label  predict features
68.282379 68.282379            1            1.0  -1.0000   0.0001        9
38.748867 9.215355            2            2.0  -1.0000   0.0174       11
21.256140 3.763414            4            4.0  -1.0000   0.8345       11
11.685329 2.114518            8            8.0  -1.0000   0.3508       11
9.457854 7.230378           16           16.0  -1.0000   0.0069       11
7.371087 5.284320           32           32.0  -1.0000   0.3561       11
7.061980 6.752873           64           64.0  -1.0000   0.6549       11
5.423309 3.784638          128          128.0  -1.0000   0.2597       11
3.252394 1.725597          211          310.0   1.0000   0.7686       11
2.140099 1.052366          330          627.0   1.0000   0.7143       11
1.671550 1.203000          660         1254.0  -1.0000   0.8054       11
1.788466 1.905383         1320         2508.0  -1.0000   0.0676        9
1.508163 1.234410         2502         5076.0   1.0000   0.3921       11
1.282862 1.060063         5061        10209.0   1.0000   0.4258        9
1.119420 0.955977        11013        20418.0  -1.0000   0.6892       11
1.017911 0.916403        22323        40836.0  -1.0000   0.5301        9
0.888435 0.758960        42171        81672.0  -1.0000   0.3500       11
0.787709 0.686983        84243       163344.0  -1.0000   0.2360        9
0.703270 0.618831       170268       326688.0  -1.0000   0.5707       11

finished run
number of examples per pass = 207361
passes used = 1
weighted example sum = 397936.000000
weighted label sum = -12936.000000
average loss = 0.684043
best constant = -0.032508
best constant's loss = 0.998943
total feature number = 2216941
```

This outputs me a predictions file `preds_ab.txt` like:

```
0.000095 7c14ae23
0.017367 3e9558bd
0.139393 6a1cd72f
0.834518 dfe76f6e
0.089810 2b88b547
```

If I calculate the ROC-AUC score of these predictions, I get a value of 0.85 which is close to what I get using scikit-learn (0.90). However the probability outputs are not calibrated at all, since they are much higher than what I would expect (close to 1%). This is the histogram.

[image: Probability histogram]

This is the reliability curve:

[image: Reliability curve]

And this is a plot of mean probabilities and positive frequencies when examples are binned by probabilities:

[image: Probabilities vs positive frequencies]

It's obvious that output probabilities are much higher than what would be expected from a well-calibrated classifier.

What am I doing wrong here? What should I investigate?

**UPDATE**

If I don't use a 100 weight for the positive class examples I get similar non-intuitive results. The mean probabity output is 0.27 (still very far from 1), the reliability plot looks even worse and ROC-AUC is 0.76.

I can confirm I have 237805 negative examples and 2195 positive ones.

Output training:

```
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
decay_learning_rate = 1
creating cache_file = impressions_rand.aa.cache
Reading datafile = impressions_rand.aa
num sources = 1
average  since         example        example  current  current  current
loss     last          counter         weight    label  predict features
0.693147 0.693147            1            1.0  -1.0000   0.0000       11
0.546724 0.400300            2            2.0  -1.0000  -0.7087       11
0.398553 0.250382            4            4.0  -1.0000  -1.3963       11
0.284506 0.170460            8            8.0  -1.0000  -2.2595       11
0.181406 0.078306           16           16.0  -1.0000  -2.8225       11
0.108136 0.034865           32           32.0  -1.0000  -4.2696       11
0.063156 0.018176           64           64.0  -1.0000  -4.7412       11
0.036415 0.009675          128          128.0  -1.0000  -4.2940       11
0.020325 0.004235          256          256.0  -1.0000  -5.9903       11
0.043248 0.066171          512          512.0  -1.0000  -5.5540       11
0.045276 0.047304         1024         1024.0  -1.0000  -4.7065       11
0.044606 0.043935         2048         2048.0  -1.0000  -6.6253       11
0.048938 0.053270         4096         4096.0  -1.0000  -5.9119       11
0.048711 0.048485         8192         8192.0  -1.0000  -2.3949       11
0.048157 0.047603        16384        16384.0  -1.0000  -9.6219       11
0.044306 0.040454        32768        32768.0  -1.0000  -8.8800       11
0.044029 0.043752        65536        65536.0  -1.0000  -5.9218        9
0.042739 0.041450       131072       131072.0  -1.0000  -3.8306       11
0.042986 0.042986       262144       262144.0  -1.0000  -6.0941       11 h
0.042321 0.041655       524288       524288.0  -1.0000  -4.0276       11 h
0.042654 0.042988      1048576      1048576.0  -1.0000  -9.9169       11 h

finished run
number of examples per pass = 216000
passes used = 7
weighted example sum = 1512000.000000
weighted label sum = -1484504.000000
average loss = 0.042763 h
best constant = -4.691161
best constant's loss = 0.051789
total feature number = 16166472
```

Output testing follows. I've read average loss being larger than best constant loss is an indicator of that something is wrong with my model learning.

```
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
using no cache
Reading datafile = impressions_rand.ab
num sources = 1
average  since         example        example  current  current  current
loss     last          counter         weight    label  predict features
78.141266 78.141266            1            1.0  -1.0000   0.0001       11
54.228148 30.315029            2            2.0  -1.0000   0.0015       11
33.279501 12.330854            4            4.0   1.0000   0.0472       11
20.358767 7.438034            8            8.0  -1.0000   0.0527       11
15.780043 11.201319           16           16.0  -1.0000   0.1657       11
13.783271 11.786498           32           32.0  -1.0000   0.0012        9
9.318714 4.854158           64           64.0  -1.0000   0.7268       11
6.797651 4.276587          128          128.0  -1.0000   0.1404        9
4.674237 2.550824          256          256.0  -1.0000   0.0516       11
3.269198 1.864159          512          512.0  -1.0000   0.4092       11
2.153033 1.036868         1024         1024.0  -1.0000   0.0425       11
1.481920 0.810807         2048         2048.0  -1.0000   0.2792       11
1.005869 0.529817         4096         4096.0  -1.0000   0.2422       11
0.676574 0.347279         8192         8192.0  -1.0000   0.3003       11
0.452924 0.229274        16384        16384.0  -1.0000   0.2579       11
0.295262 0.137600        32768        32768.0  -1.0000   0.2833       11
0.191513 0.087763        65536        65536.0  -1.0000   0.2616        9
0.126758 0.062003       131072       131072.0  -1.0000   0.2670       11

finished run
number of examples per pass = 207361
passes used = 1
weighted example sum = 207361.000000
weighted label sum = -203423.000000
average loss = 0.099565
best constant = -0.981009
best constant's loss = 0.037621
total feature number = 2217159
```

Comment: First thing I would do to improve this result is avoid hash collisions: you have over 200k examples, and roughly 10x more features (~10 features per example). leaving the default `-b 18` (about 262k unique features) seems to be insufficient.  Try `-b 24` for a start. Does it improve the result?

Comment: Also: unless there's some serious irregularity making positive labels appearing together, there's no need to shuffle examples that come in natural time order.

Comment: You should also use `-t` when testing, so you don't continue training on the test data.

Comment: The updated testing is really strange: as you noticed the average loss is worse than the best constant's loss. What is the test loss if you omit `--link=logistic`? (It should stay the same, I would say, but I am not sure and cannot try it now.)

Comment: I solved it thanks to your comments!! I was not using `-t` for testing and also I had to specify `--loss_function logistic` during prediction as well. Otherwise the reported losses are totally wrong.

Comment: The model was being updated during testing using the default loss instead of logistic, wrecking the probability outputs. Will post answer!

Comment: This is unrelated to the question but I think compensating weight should be given to the downsampled class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it thanks to Martin Popel and arielf comments. :)

1. I forgot to use `-t` when generating the predictions.
2. I didn't specify `--loss_function logisitc` when generating the predictions.

As a result, the model was being updated while testing using the default loss function instead of the logistic one, destroying the model and producing wrong results.

Takeouts:

1. Use `--loss_function logistic` also during test to see correct loss outputs.
2. Remember to use `-t` if you don't want to update your model while predicting.

This is how the output looks now when testing (without example weighting):

```
$ vw -d impressions_rand.ab --link logistic --loss_function logistic -i model.vw -t -p preds.txt
only testing
predictions = preds.txt
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
using no cache
Reading datafile = impressions_rand.ab
num sources = 1
average  since         example        example  current  current  current
loss     last          counter         weight    label  predict features
0.000053 0.000053            1            1.0  -1.0000   0.0001       11
0.000370 0.000687            2            2.0  -1.0000   0.0007       11
1.252868 2.505366            4            4.0   1.0000   0.0067       11
0.638249 0.023630            8            8.0  -1.0000   0.0036       11
0.322060 0.005872           16           16.0  -1.0000   0.0031       11
0.164750 0.007439           32           32.0  -1.0000   0.0000        9
0.084911 0.005072           64           64.0  -1.0000   0.0081       11
0.076905 0.068899          128          128.0  -1.0000   0.0004        9
0.055126 0.033347          256          256.0  -1.0000   0.0000       11
0.052986 0.050847          512          512.0  -1.0000   0.0133       11
0.038351 0.023715         1024         1024.0  -1.0000   0.0000       11
0.037059 0.035767         2048         2048.0  -1.0000   0.0167       11
0.038848 0.040637         4096         4096.0  -1.0000   0.0112       11
0.038903 0.038957         8192         8192.0  -1.0000   0.0281       11
0.041625 0.044348        16384        16384.0  -1.0000   0.0001       11
0.042526 0.043426        32768        32768.0  -1.0000   0.0218       11
0.042538 0.042551        65536        65536.0  -1.0000   0.0000        9
0.042150 0.041763       131072       131072.0  -1.0000   0.0019       11

finished run
number of examples per pass = 207361
passes used = 1
weighted example sum = 207361.000000
weighted label sum = -203423.000000
average loss = 0.042438
best constant = -4.647395
best constant's loss = 0.053670
total feature number = 2217159
```

You see now reported `average loss` is less than `best constant's loss`, and the iterative average losses lay also in the expected interval.

Also, the output probabilities now make perfect sense:

[image: Mean probabilities vs. frequencies]

Answer (score 2):

You say you have one positive example per 100 negative examples on average in the training set. However, you put 100 times more weight on the positive examples, which is (almost) equivalent to repeating each positive example 100 times in the training set. This way the average predicted probability should be around 50%. So you should not be surprised it is not around 1%.

According to the vw output you provided, it seems that there are more than 100 negative examples per one positive in the training set impressions_rand.aa, so the "weighted label sum" is negative (otherwise it should be around 0). Thus, the average predicted probability is not 50% but around 36%.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately not weighting positive examples outputs unreliable probabilities as well. I've updated the question with training/testing outputs without weighting.